# which type does pthread_create need on the third argument

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

this is the right use of pthread_create with no warning:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void  *check(void *temp) {
    int* i = (int *)temp;
    printf("%d\n", *i);
}
int main(void) {
    pthread_t check_thread;
    int i = 1;
    pthread_create(&check_thread, NULL, check , (void  *)&i);
    pthread_join(check_thread, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

but the following code can also run well, just change void *check to void check:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void check(void *temp) {
    int* i = (int *)temp;
    printf("%d\n", *i);
}
int main(void) {
    pthread_t check_thread;
    int i = 1;
    pthread_create(&check_thread, NULL, check, (void  *)&i);
    pthread_join(check_thread, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

if i change check to &check, it can also run well

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void check(void *temp) {
    int* i = (int *)temp;
    printf("%d\n", *i);
}
int main(void) {
    pthread_t check_thread;
    int i = 1;
    pthread_create(&check_thread, NULL, &check, (void  *)&i);
    pthread_join(check_thread, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

i see the thrid argument of pthread_create is: void *(*start_routine) (void *)
can someone tell me what does it mean?

Comment: This looks like C, so what's the reason for tagging the different language C++? And what's specifically unclear about the documentation?

Comment: As others have stated, this isn't C++, but the third argument of `pthead_create` is a *function pointer*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the POSIX standard for `pthread_create()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <pthread.h>
>
> int pthread_create(pthread_t *restrict thread,
>        const pthread_attr_t *restrict attr,
>        void *(*start_routine)(void*), void *restrict arg);
> ```

That means that the third argument to `pthread_create()` must be a function pointer of the form `void *(*start_routine)(void*)`.  The function pointer passed must refer to a function
declared and defined as

```
void *start_routine( void *arg )
{
    void *ptr = ...;

    ...
    return( ptr );
}
```

Period.  End of discussion.  Full stop.

You are invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by not passing a function of the type `void *(*start_routine) (void *)` as the third argument to `pthread_create()`.

Per [**J.2 Undefined behavior**, paragraph 1 of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2):

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>
> ...
>
> - A pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type.

"Works with no **observed** issue" is covered by "undefined behavior".  "Program crashes" is also covered.

Answer (score 1):

The deal of the C standard is to write portable code, that could run on any conforming platform. The fact that this runs on your platform without visible errors, does not mean that it would on other platforms. Reasons for failure could e.g be that `pthread_join` could try to access a hardware register with the return value.

Answer (score 1):

It is nothing but a function pointer. Lets break it down.
void *(*start_routine) (void *)

```
void* -> return type of function
start_routine -> function pointer name 
void* -> argument type
```

the address of the function you pass will be assigned to function pointer start_routine and start_routine will be invoked as new thread from kernel.